Please help identify this 30mm diameter lens thread
I bought this camera from Ali Express

The lens it comes with has a thread on it, and I'm not sure what thread it is. It measures 30.68mm (1.2075") in diameter with calipers. The thread pitch is about 0.75mm or 0.03"



What type of lens mount or thread is this? I thought it might be C-Mount, but the diagrams I have seen imply that it should measure 1" across the thread.


Update:
Thanks to scottbb for that insightful answer. Turns out it is a CS-Mount lens with some kind of adapter on it. Still, it would be interesting to know what that thread is.


It really looks like the lens is a CS-mount lens. It's printed right on the side: 1.25" CS IR 3MP.
It appears the black threads are a thread adapter, with internal C-mount threads (1-inch × 32 TPI, "1-32UN-2A" specification). The outside threads are probably a 30 mm, maybe 30.5 mm thread? With a thread pitch of 0.75 mm that you think, it's probably M30×0.75. I would have said possibly a Thor Labs SM30 mount (M30.5×0.5), but not with the 0.75 thread pitch you have.
If it weren't for the fact that you've measured correctly, I would assume the adapter was using a TFL mount thread (M35×0.75 mm). Is basically "C-mount, but larger throat), because it's flange distance of 17.526 mm is the same as the C-mount's flange distance.

Well I'll be damned! It is a CS mount with an adapter! Why on earth would they go to the effort to adapt it to something non-standard?

@Rocketmagnet well, maybe it is a standard, just not a US or Euro standard we're used to. TFL isn't a commonly recognized standard, but the thinking with it is just "let mount larger lenses to image onto larger sensors, and just keep the C-mount flange distance". Maybe the camera's lens mount component has clues? Because I'm willing to bet whichever company made it, didn't make it custom or non-standard for no reason. I bet a lot of similar Alibaba cameras (same sensor) have a similar lens mount. ¯\(ツ)/¯

@Rocketmagnet I had another idea why they might have used the thread adapter: if the external and internal threads are different pitches, then the thread adapter can essentially act as a "calibration" or fine-tuning mechanism, to adjust the lens-to-sensor distance and still have the lens printing info facing up. Basically, a back-and-forth calibration between tightening the camera set screw, rotating just the lens, then loosening the set screw and rotating the lens+adapter, to dial in the CS mount flange distance and keep the lens printing aimed up. Maybe?

That's an interesting idea, but I doubt they're thinking that advanced. Maybe they just had a job load of non-standard camera bodies and needed to fit standard lenses onto them.
